# Young mango tree leaves get blackish and fall off

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, fruit-trees, diseases, tree-care

I have planted a mango seed and it was growing fine until a few days ago I noticed that one of the leaves had started going blackish. When I touched it, it fell. Yesterday I noticed that another one had started looking the same as the first one and today I found a third one. The last two are yet to fall off.

A bit more context: it stays in my room and is at room temperature next to the heating and right under the window, I try to moisture it and water it between one and two times a week, so I doubt it has anything being overwatered. I am afraid it might be sick and have no idea what to do. Should I change its soil?

I have also had another mango for an year and a half that I gave away but it has never had such problems.

Edit: I have also noticed that the lines on the upper leaves have started going black.

[image: Sick leaf]
[image: Sick leaf]
[image: Leaf number 2]

[image: Leaf number 3 from today]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a watering problem.  Do you check the soil before you water your plant?  Make sure the top 1-2" are dry before you add more water.  The soil should never be allowed to completely dry out, but it needs to dry some between watering.  This is very important for the roots to breath.  Roots require oxygen.  They can not get it from soil that is saturated.

The only other thing it could be, but I do not think so, it has cold damage.  Were the leaves touching the window.  I assume you have giving it plenty of light.